# Get last inserted id of any table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm importing a .sql file via php. My .sql file contains multiple tables and I want the last inserted id of a particular table.
So, how to get last inserted id of any table by table name?

Any idea how to get the id?
Please don't suggest, get id by select query to get MAX id.

Comment: SELECT id FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: You got lot of tables?  may be you can make a Query like this one (pseudocode):
select top 1 id from (
select top 1 id, "WORKERS" as tableName from WorkersTable order by id desc
UNION
select top 1 id, "HOMES" as tableName from HOMESTable order by id desc
) order by id desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `auto_increment` is defined, that last inserted auto increment id can be retrieved from `information_schema.tables`:

```
select IF(auto_increment = 1, 
          'No row has been inserted', 
          auto_increment - @@auto_increment_increment) As LastInsertedId
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'DBName' and table_name = 'TableName';
```

Answer (score 1):

We had.

```
id | value
1  |  10
3  |  20
```

Then we inserted `2 | 15`, so it had become

```
id | value
1  |  10
2  |  15
3  |  20
```

(Remind, we have a `.sql` file, not a live connection)

And now you want to know, that the last one was `2`? If so — it's impossible. `.sql` file doesn't keep that kind of information, only bare data and some meta.

Comment: Not possible  by mysql function...?

Comment: As you said, you have `.sql` file, not a live connection. So — there is no that kind of information here (what was last inserted), only data. Btw, why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in both mysql and mysqli.

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('abc', 'xyz', 'abc@example.com')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);}
```

in mysql

```
       mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
       mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
        VALUES ('abc', 'xyz', 'abc@example.com')";
        if (mysql_query($sql)) {
            $last_id = mysql_insert_id();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these functions

If you're using PDO, use [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

If you're using Mysqli, use [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

<sub>But if you have to, use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).</sub>

Comment: From which table it take the last inserted id..?Might be possible simultaneously there will be entry in 3 table and it will return the id from second table and I want the id of First table.

Comment: @Ritesh It will return the last inserted ID of the last INSERT statement in your current connection. What _you_ want seems impossible.